# How can I set UIButton default to OFF?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiswitch, userdefaults

I have an app where UISwitches should, by default, be set to off. The switches are functioning properly and the app is remembering the set state of the UISwitches, but they are defaulting to the on position (green). I need them to default to the off position (grey). I know this would have something to do with a boolean value but how can I implement this into the current code that I have? Code included: thanks!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            switchButton.isOn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")
            switchButton2.isOn =  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")
            switchButton3.isOn =  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")
            switchButton4.isOn =  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")
            switchButton5.isOn =  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")
            switchButton6.isOn =  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")
            switchButton7.isOn =  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")
            switchButton8.isOn =  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")
            switchButton9.isOn =  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")

//@IBAction Example: 

       @IBAction func saveSwitchPressed(_ sender: UISwitch) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "switchState")
```

Comment: With the code you have shown the switches should default to off the first time you run the app; If you request a boolean from `UserDefaults` and there is no key with that name (which would be the case the first time the app was run) then it will return `false`, which should have the switch off.

Comment: Thanks Paul - it seems that the switches are set to OFF when running the app for the first time, as you mentioned. However, when switching 1 toggle to the ON position, backing out of that view controller, and then going back in, all of the switches turn to the ON position.

Comment: All of your switches are getting their value from the same UserDefaults key - I assumed that was a typo in your question.  If that is your actual code then you need to change it to use a different key for each switch

Comment: That was indeed the problem, all working now - thank you, appreciate it! Did you want to answer the question so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code you have shown the switches will default to off the first time you run the app; If you request a boolean from `UserDefaults` and there is no key with that name (which would be the case the first time the app was run) then it will return false, which will have the switch off.

You do need to use a different key name for each switch, otherwise all of the switches will have the same state.